# Why can't Harry see the Thestrals before seeing Cedric die?

Tags: harry-potter

If Harry has seen his mother die, as revealed in *The Deathly Hallows*, why couldn't he see the thestrals before *The Order of the Phoenix* (after he's seen Cedric Diggory die)?

Comment: Also related: [Why COULD Harry See Thestrals Following Cedric Diggory's Death?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9016/why-could-harry-see-thestrals-following-cedric-diggorys-death)

Comment: Specifically, [apoorv020's answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/8186/5184) covers this.