# How come Harry didn't see Thestrals after "killing" Quirrell?

Tags: harry-potter, magic

In Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone, Quirrell nearly killed Harry. However, Harry placed his hands on Quirrell causing him to perish. Wether or not this is seen as actually killing Quirrell or as self defense, Harry actually sees Quirrell **die**.

So how come he couldn't see thestrals since year two?

Comment: Could you please direct me to the part where this question is actually answered? :)

Comment: your point about "Harry actually sees Quirrel die" is mistaken, per the (handwaved, maybe) interview where JKR states he had passed out before seeing Quirrell die (see answer linked above). No seeing of death, no seeing of Thestrals :)

Comment: My mistake, thank you for clearing that!!

Comment: @Jenayah Well then technically he didn't "see" Cedric die either: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9016/why-could-harry-see-thestrals-following-cedric-diggorys-death?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @Alex yeah, and in the quoted interview, JKR basically handwaves it with "you know, he hadn't processed it yet" :p

Comment: @Jenayah That's more of an explanation of why his seeing them was delayed. I'm saying that her handwaving for Quirrel kind of undermines the Cedric situation to begin with.